# Used Snapshot to revert but still see refrence to various things

Tags: iphone, objective-c

As i was changing my code and used another .h and .m files added, i decided this wasnt the best way, so i reverted back to my old code via snapshot feature.

When i did, i ran my code and now i get this

> Unknown class AsynchronousImageView in
>   Interface Builder file.

I looked at all my source code and my UI and there are no links but even if there was, why did the snapshot let it carry across?

Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, Build > Clean all targets solved that issue.

Its strange why from a snapshot that occurred.